# Artifactory recreates built-in certificates on every restart

Tags: docker, ssl, artifactory

I'm trying to use the inbuilt TLS support of Artifactory OSS 7.5.7 using custom CA and custom certificates in docker environment. Artifactory itself is running well with below docker env variable - helps others maybe.

```
JF_SHARED_TOMCAT_CONNECTOR_EXTRA = "<Connector port='8443' protocol='org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol' scheme='https' secure='true' SSLEnabled='true' maxThreads='200'><SSLHostConfig protocols='TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2'><Certificate certificateFile='/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/ssl/certs/artifactory.pem' certificateKeyFile='/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/ssl/keys/artifactory-key.pem' /></SSLHostConfig></Connector>"
```

On the other hand, I'm hardly getting progress for the UI module. Following the formal documentation in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+TLS+Certificates , access.config.import.yml configuration with below content made UI accessible through TLS using the built-in certificates in docker image. So far so good.

```
security:
  tls: true
```

After replacing the built-in certificates, as documentation says, with my custom CA and certificates and restarting docker container, my certificates are gone and auto-generated certificates take place. As far as I see, each docker restart recreates the built-in certificates, so it shouldn't be about the certificates validity.

My question is that, is this what it should be? Is there any way or configuration that given certificates are not overriden? Or, is there any other way to point the paths for the certificates that should be taken into consideration by the container?

Notes:

1. As you may guess, Artifactory will be server-only in this set up.
2. Apache or Nginx alternatives may be considered, but I suppose my first bet would be Artifactory-based solution.
3. Actually, I wanted to check the source codes, I suppose there should be some condition not to override the files but I wasn't able to find them.

Thanks, in advance.